# openSuSE, Linux, cannot create directory-permission denied

Tags: linux, opensuse

I am using openSuse 12.3, and logged in as a user.
I am trying to create a directory in the `/home/` , but getting permission denied.

any idea, how to fix this.

```
harbir@linux-gn77:/home> mkdir testDir
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘testDir’: Permission denied
harbir@linux-gn77:/home>
```

Comment: You will need administrative privileges. Why are you making this directory in `/home`? Why not in `/home/user` which is *your* home directory?

Comment: hmm, pardon me, I think you have a very good point. Well I will blame of on 0430 time and lack of coffee.
Please, put your comment as the answer, if it works, I can mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only root can create directories under `/home`. You typically put a directory under `/home` for each user's account. Running the command `getent passwd` will show you which users have home directories located here:

```
$ getent passwd | grep /home
saml:x:1000:1000:saml:/home/saml:/bin/bash
samtest:x:1001:1001::/home/samtest:/bin/bash
```

Also you generally do not make these directories by hand, but rather use a tool such as `adduser` to create new user accounts and through it specify sub directories to make for user's under `/home`.

```
$ sudo adduser
  -d, --home-dir HOME_DIR       home directory of the new account
```

If you truly want to just make a sub directory under `/home` for some pre-existing user to use, in addition to their already existing `/home` directory you can do so like this:

```
$ sudo mkdir /home/somedir
$ sudo chown -R myuser.somegroup /home/somedir
```

If you're merely trying to make a directory under your user's `/home/user` directory then do so using one of these methods instead:

```
$ mkdir ~/testDir
$ mkdir $HOME/testDir
$ mkdir /home/harbir/testDir
$ cd /home/harbir; mkdir testDir
```

Answer (score 0):

I got here after messsing up permissions on my /home mount after re-sizing the /root and /home logical volumes. I deleted and re-created the /home volume and discovered that /home needs 755 permissions to allow users to login and access their /home/user directories.
I did :
`chmod 755 /home` and that did the trick.